# mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: python, localhost, mysql-connector

[image]***I Have a Problem with this code Here***

I Have An ids on my Table and Its Primary key and set to Auto Increment

```
def register():

    if (t1.get()==""  or t2.get()=="" or t3.get()==""):
        messagebox.showinfo("Result","Please Complete the Provided Details!")

    else:
        databases = mysql.connector.connect(
        host ="localhost",
        user = "userdata",
        password = "",
        database = "facerecog"
        )

        cursors = databases.cursor()
        cursors.execute("SELECT * from record")
        result = cursors.fetchall()
```

**Heres My Id set**

```
id = 2 #This is the ID That I set
```

for x in result:

```
  id ++1 #auto increment from my python
    sql = "INSERT INTO record(ids,names,course_year,positions) values(%s, %s ,%s , %s)"
    val = (id, t1.get(), t2.get(), t3.get())
    cursors.execute(sql,val)
    databases.commit()
```

**The Error I get**

```
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

**How Can I auto_increment it?**

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is auto-incremented in your database table, I don't think you should include the ID column in your insert statement. When you insert values, the ID column will be filled automatically inside your database table. It doesn't need you to input any value into its column in your sql statement. Rather try:

```
  sql = "INSERT INTO record(names,course_year,positions) values(%s ,%s , %s)"
    val = ( t1.get(), t2.get(), t3.get())
```

But I think Python uses

```
    (t1.text(), t2.text(), t3.text())
```

to set the values into the database and your t1, t2, t3 must be a textfield (lineEdit) where values can be inputted, all depends on what you're using though

Comment: Yes It worked Thank you But the problem I am facing now is my program will Record data to my database and it takes picture 4 picture will be taken. But on database there are 4 record will be recorded same name but not on ID

Comment: If a suggestion works, it is expected you upvote it. (smiles). As for your recent issue about 4 picture and 4 record, can you explain better?

Comment: What I mean my program if you put text to t1,t2,t3 and click register It takes 4 photos. But on my database It records 4 data example id 1,2,3,4 same text

Comment: Is it photos you're inputing? I don't understand where the photos are coming in.

Comment: Up To the Answer My code The photos Coming In my Folder and the data sentto my database

Comment: I still don't understand you. You said you register 4 photos and your table records 4 data. If you have 5 columns in your table including the ID column which is auto-incremented, you're to input 4 values into the table. How many values are you inputing into it? Is it 4 photos you're inputing into it? If yes, what is the datatype of the photo column in your database?

Comment: What I mean is  photos will be saved on c/users/img/ it named user1.1jpg to user1.4jpg But on the database id and what I input to t1,t2,t3 will be sent to database but the problem is instead of 1 it will record 4 data and its all the same except the ID

Answer (score 0):

```
def register():

    if (t1.get()==""  or t2.get()=="" or t3.get()==""):
        messagebox.showinfo("Result","Please Complete the Provided Details!")

    else:
        databases = mysql.connector.connect(
        host ="localhost",
        user = "userdata",
        password = "",
        database = "facerecog"
        )

        cursors = databases.cursor()
        cursors.execute("SELECT * from record")
        result = cursors.fetchall()

        

    for x in result:
        
        sql = "INSERT INTO record(names,course_year,positions) values(%s ,%s , %s)"
        val = ( t1.get(), t2.get(), t3.get())
        cursors.execute(sql,val)
        databases.commit()

        face_classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
        def face_cropped(img):
            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            # scaling factor = 1.3
            # minimum neighbor = 5
            if faces is ():
                return None
            for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
                cropped_face = cv2.rectangle(img,(1, 0),(0,0),(255,0,0),1)
            return cropped_face

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        img_id = 0
```

**[image: Here Capturing Images]**

```
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if face_cropped(frame) is not None:

            img_id+=1

            face = cv2.resize(face_cropped(frame), (1024,768))
            #face = cv2.cvtColor(face,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

            file_name_path = "img/"+str (t1.get())+""+str(id)+"."+str(img_id)+".jpg"

            cv2.imwrite(file_name_path, face)

            cv2.putText(face, str(img_id), (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0,255,0), 2)

            cv2.imshow("Cropped face", face)

        if cv2.waitKey(1)==1 or int(img_id)==4:
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```